# node rd kafka repeats delivery reports from beginning for each message

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

`delivery-report` event gets called each time for every message produced and keep giving delivery reports from beginning. For ex, we will get delivery report with offset 1 for first message. For second message, we will get two delivery reports with offset 2. For third, we will get 3 delivery message with offset 3 and so on.

```
producer.on('delivery-report', function (err, report) {

   console.log("delivery report received");
   console.log('delivery-report: ' + JSON.stringify(report));

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `delivery-report` event there is a `once` binding which delivers only one delivery report for each message.

```
producer.once('delivery-report', function (err, report) {

   console.log("delivery report received");
   console.log('delivery-report: ' + JSON.stringify(report));

});
```